# How do I fit authors into a single line?

Tags: beamer, line-breaking

How do I fit authors into a single line?

```
\title{An example}
\author{Multiple authors with long name will be splited into two lines}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

I use the `shrink` option, but the result is ugly. Is there a better way?

```
\begin{frame}[shrink=20]
    \titlepage
\end{frame}
```

---

With the help of @egreg, use the follow command:

```
\protect\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{Multiple authors with long name will be splited into two lines}
```

It does fit it into a single line, but the text does not center, as shown in the following figure.

[image]

PS: The theme I use is `warsaw`.

Comment: `\author{\protect\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{...}}`? But why not having the authors one above the other?

Comment: @egreg, thx, it works. How to align it center?

Comment: @egreg, would you pls explain a bit more about `\protect` and `!` ?

Comment: ＠egrep, `\author{\protect\centering\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{}}` doesn't work.

Comment: It occupies the whole space reserved for the text, which is not the whole slide.

Comment: @egreg, thx again. I added a figure to the question. Pls check it.

Comment: Without knowing the themes you're using, the answer can only be partial.

Comment: ＠egreg, the theme I use is `warsaw`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The title is set with some spacing on the left and right, so the result appears not to be centered if the author list is scaled to `\textwidth`, because the line is overfull.

The added space is 16pt in the standard set up of `beamer`, so

```
\documentclass{beamer}

%\usetheme{Warsaw}

\title{An example}
\author[ABC DEF]{% <---- FIX THE SHORT AUTHOR LIST
  \texorpdfstring{\hspace*{-8pt}}{}%
  \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
    Multiple authors with long name will be split into two lines%
  }%
  \texorpdfstring{\hspace*{-8pt}}{}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\titlepage

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Note that a “short author” argument has to be given, or themes that show the author list in the slides will have a hard time fitting it.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use `\protect`?

Comment: @SparkandShine Well, it turns out it was not needed